# How Fast Does MongoDB Indices Grow in Size?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, full-text-search, space-complexity

In a MongoDB database that is indexed at one field, called field `I`, if the logical size of the database is growing at the rate of `n`, what would the growth rate of the size of the indices be? (Let's say field `I` contains only text.)

There are a lot of documents out there concerning the time complexity of search operation using an indexed field within a MongoDB collection, but I just can't find any documentation regarding the growth rate of the size of the indices.

Comment: Is `n` the number of documents, the size of the data in memory, or the size of the data on disk?

Comment: I think `n` is usually the number of documents. On the other hand, that directly correlates to the logical size of the data being stored in the database, not the total size on the disk (which would include the size of indices).

Comment: The data on disk would be highly compressed, the data in memory can take advantage of prefix compression as well.  Going with 'n' is the count, if none of the documents have an array in the indexed field, that would mean 'n' keys in the index.